# How to refactor / aggregate numeric values in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a POJO like the following:

```
public class AgentSales {
   private String agent;
   private int month;
   private int year;
   private int salesCount;

   public AgentSales(String agent, int month, int year, int salesCount) {
       // initializers ...
   } 

   // getters & setters
   // ...
}
```

And a collection like the following:

```
ArrayList<AgentSales> salesList = new ArrayList<AgentSales>();

salesList.add(new AgentSales("Ben", 1, 2013, 3));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Ben", 1, 2013, 2));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Ben", 2, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Ben", 3, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Ben", 2, 2013, 2));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Tim", 1, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Tim", 1, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Tim", 2, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Tim", 4, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Tim", 2, 2013, 5));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Joe", 2, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Joe", 2, 2013, 2));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Joe", 3, 2013, 1));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Joe", 3, 2013, 2));
salesList.add(new AgentSales("Joe", 3, 2013, 1));
```

How could I refactor / aggregate the contents of this ArrayList, so that the multiple items corresponding to the same month and agent are merged into 1 with the salesCount value summed up?

```
Agent | month | year | sales count
----------------------------------
Ben   |   1   | 2013 |      5
Ben   |   2   | 2013 |      3
Ben   |   3   | 2013 |      1 
Tim   |   1   | 2013 |      2
Tim   |   2   | 2013 |      6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a `HashMap<String,AgentSales>` where the key is agent+month+year to aggregate.

kinda like this:

```
HashMap<String,AgentSales> aggregate = new HashMap<>();
for (AgentSales as : salesList) {
   String key = as.getAgent() + as.getMonth() + as.getYear();
   AgentSales existing = aggregate.get(key);
   if (existing==null) {
      aggregate.put(key,as);
      continue;
   }
   AgentSales combined = new AgentSales(as.getAgent(), as.getMonth(), as.getYear(), as.getSalesCount()+exisgint.getSalesCount());
   aggregate.put(key, combined); 
}
```

now you have the combined values by agent+month+year in the map. you can then get them back as an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<AgentSales> asList = new ArrayList<>(aggregate.values());
```

then you can sort this (by writing a `Comparator<AgentSales>` or making AgentSales implement `Comparable<AgentSales>`) and print it out

Comment: If I use a concatenated key like agent+month+year, how would I process it to get the aggregated values back to the ArrayList in the same format?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use a `FastList` instead of an `ArrayList`, and then use the `aggregateBy()` method. This assumes you create a Key class which implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```
Function<AgentSales, Key> groupBy = new Function<AgentSales, Key>()
{
    public Key valueOf(AgentSales agentSales)
    {
        return new Key(agentSales.agent, agentSales.year, agentSales.month);
    }
};

Function2<Integer, AgentSales, Integer> nonMutatingAggregator =
    new Function2<Integer, AgentSales, Integer>()
{
    public Integer value(Integer sum, AgentSales agentSales)
    {
        return sum + agentSales.salesCount;
    }
};

MutableMap<Key, Integer> aggregate =
    salesList.aggregateBy(groupBy, Functions0.value(0), nonMutatingAggregator);
System.out.println(aggregate.keyValuesView().makeString("\n"));
```

This prints something like:

```
agent='Ben', month=1, year=2013}:5
agent='Joe', month=2, year=2013}:3
agent='Ben', month=3, year=2013}:1
agent='Ben', month=2, year=2013}:3
agent='Joe', month=3, year=2013}:4
agent='Tim', month=4, year=2013}:1
agent='Tim', month=1, year=2013}:2
agent='Tim', month=2, year=2013}:6
```

When Java 8 comes out, we can replace the Functions with lambdas.

```
MutableMap<Key, Integer> aggregate = salesList.aggregateBy(
    agentSales -> new Key(agentSales.agent, agentSales.year, agentSales.month), 
    () -> 0, 
    (sum, agentSales) -> sum + agentSales.salesCount);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your desing seems flawed from the beginning. You should have created an `Agent` class which would contain personal information and then `AgentSales` which would contain a reference to the agent and a sales value.

With these classes you could sort the list by `Agent` and sum values in one iteration for each group of `AgentSales` which have the same `Agent`.

As it is, I would suggest writing a custom `Comparator` and equality comparer and, using those, do the same thing I described above.

Comment: The design was a requirement for getting object relational mapped values in a similar pattern from a messy database.